# WiFi Direct reassigning Group Owner during ongoing connection

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I would like to change the group owner (GO) during an ongoing connection between two (multiple after I am done with two) devices. Is this possible? For example, device A and device B formed a group, and A is the group owner. After a while, I would like to pass the GO duty to B. I have to options in my mind: i) Can I do it during ongoing connection? if yes how? or ii) do I have to dissolve the group first, and then from a group assigning B as group owner by using GroupOwnerIntent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the GO on active connections, thus yes, you do need to disconnect all devices first.

If you have a logic to determine which one is going to be the GO, then I would suggest using CreateGroup function to create the GO, and have others to connect to it once they see it advertising its presence.

Comment: I've implemented it. Thank you very much for the information!

Comment: Hi Dr. Jukka. As you suggested I used createGroup() method in order to create the GO. However, when I try to connect to that GO, the GO device status seems to be stuck at "Invited". This happens if future-client doesn't remember the GO as a group (persistent connection). If the future-client remembers the GO from previous persistent connection, then I can connect. Is there any way that I deal with the necessity of remembering a previous persistent group?